# Nested for loops in Shellscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help with a Shellscript.

I have a For loop in my script, which creates files names with a variable names. like file.$variable.

For example I have a list of, servers in a servers.txt file. from there i will read the server and connect to them and get some data from the each server. The filenames will be file.$server. 
From that i am using For loop and creating the files of each server.

```
for server in `cat servers.txt`; do
ssh $server ls | awk '{print $2}' | tee -a files.$server.txt
```

This one working fine.

Now, from those generated files I need to run one more for loop to read all the files and read the content of the each file and give it as input to another command.
ex:

```
for file in `cat files.$servers.txt`; do
cat $file | awk '{print $2}' | tee -a column.$file.txt
```

But, not working for my in the second loop. Please help.

In a nut shell its a nested loop. Excuse me for my English.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve] (please follow and read that link). The `for` loops in your question are incomplete; there's no `done` at the end. And you're asking about a nested loop, but you haven't actually shown us one. We can't guess what else you might have omitted because you assumed it wasn't important.

Comment: As an aside -- see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also, it's more efficient to `awk '{print $2}' <"$file"` or `awk '{print $2}' "$file"` rather than `cat $file | awk '{print $2}'`; the first two let `awk` read from the file directly, the latter starts two separate programs (`cat` and `awk`) and has the latter reading from the output of the former. And quotes around `"$file"` are necessary to work with interesting names (or interesting shell runtime settings). Consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: `ssh $server ls | awk '{print $2}' | tee -a files.$server.txt` creates a file with empty lines (unless your filenames have spaces in them). I do not understand how that is 'working fine'.